# Use of `new Function` and performance issues

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a script file via AJAX, and to run its content I'm doing this:

```
new Function('someargument',xhr.responseText)(somevalue);
```

However, according to MDN:

> `Function` objects created with the `Function` constructor are parsed when the function is created. This is less efficient than declaring a function and calling it within your code, because functions declared with the function statement are parsed with the rest of the code.

I really don't quite get it. If a function is declared, it still has to be parsed from the string format of the file, so why would running a loaded string through `new Function` be any less efficient?

This is really more of a curiosity thing for me. I can understand why it would be bad in a loop (having to re-parse the same string), but for something like this I don't think there's any issue, is there?

Comment: It's parsed almost like eval is, which is known to be slow. I *suppose* it should be a little faster, as is doesn't have to hook up the scope chain.

Comment: Don't send functions by AJAX, send data. Have your functions defined in a _.js_ or `<script>`.

Comment: @PaulS. This is intended for a preloader script.

Comment: Also, this is what happens when that is evaluated: http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.2.1. That happens at runtime, so it could be perceived as even slower.

Comment: In this particular case, which is actually an interesting use of `Function()`, it doesn't matter and I doubt it could be done in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* the MDN docs are referring to something like this:

```
var f = new Function("return 5;");
```

As opposed to:

```
function f() { return 5; }
```

The former version is less efficient because it first creates an actual `String` object ("return 5") *in JavaScript* and then parses that string to create a `Function` object. The latter parses the code without an intermediate string.

That said, in your case since you're loading the JavaScript code dynamically I don't think there's really any getting around it.

Comment: +1 to both you and Ryan, but you'll get the Accept for being a little simpler with your example.

Answer (score 6):

I think what they are saying is that if you use the function constructor in your code like this:

```
new Function('bar', 'console.log(bar);'));
```

The function body is parsed twice: the first time as a string when the code is loaded, and the second time when the function is constructed at runtime.  In your case, you are creating the function from an ajax response after the code has been parsed, so really its a whole different deal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the author of that MDN article intended, but here is one interpretation.

Many modern JS interpreters use an optimizing compiler to produce native code.

For example, ["JavaScriptCore, the WebKit JS implementation"](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/10/28/javascriptcore-the-webkit-js-implementation) says:

> In that case there is tiered compilation between the three forms: initial parsing and compilation produces bytecode, that can be optimized with the method JIT, that can be optimized by the DFG JIT. In practice, though, on most platforms the interpreter is not included, so that all code runs through the method JIT.

The more complete the picture an optimizing compiler has of the code it's compiling, the more optimizations it can perform, so the more highly optimized the function can be.  For example, if you know that every reference to a function is used to call it immediately with a string as its sole argument because it is defined in a strict function body, then you might be able to avoid allocating a function object for it at all and perform certain optimizations in its body.

When you call `new Function`, the optimizing compiler does not get the context necessary to do those and other optimizations.

Comment: Okay, so how would this apply to my situation: The code using `new Function` is a preloader, and the code being parsed is the actual script for the game I'm working on.

Comment: @Kolink, Does it apply to your situation?  Have you benchmarked to see if it has any performance impact?  Don't make performance decisions without data when the data is easy to collect.  Just try what you have, and the equivalent using a `<script src>` and compare the times on your supported browser sets.