# Fetch operation is a lot slower when calling it from a JavaScript code then when calling it from react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

So I have developed an app that crawl data from a some html sites.
I wanted to keep the parser code separated from the app. So when I want to make changes to a parser I wont have to republish my app. So I could have my parsers `JS` files on `Github` for example and then let my app download and parse those parsers.

I have been able to accomplish that but then I got a weird problem. When calling fetch from the code in `react-native`(`typescript`) is a lot faster then when I call those fetch operation from the `JavaScript`.

Why is that? I am using the same `HttpClient` object the different is that I am calling it from different place.

Here is one of the [Parser](https://github.com/AlenToma/NovelManager-public/blob/parser/parsers-container/1.0.8/Comrademao.js)

### Here is the parser translator.

```js
    private async loadParser() {
        try {
            this.script = await HttpClient.GetText(this.onlineParserURI);

            if (this.script && this.script.length >= 5) {
                this.searchFunction = new Function(...this.parameter, "filter", "page", this.script + "\n return search(filter, page);");
                this.getNovelFunction = new Function(...this.parameter, "novelUrl", this.script + "\n return getNovel(novelUrl);");
                this.latestFunction = new Function(...this.parameter, "page", this.script + "\n return latest(page);");
                this.getChapterFunction = new Function(...this.parameter, "url", this.script + "\n return getChapter(url);");
                var detaliFunc = new Function(...this.parameter, this.script + "\n return parserDetali();");
                var item = detaliFunc(...this.types); // the constructor eg name, url etc
                this.url = item.url;
                this.latestUrl = item.latestUrl;
                this.searchUrl = item.searchUrl;
                this.id = item.id;
                this.parserLanguage = item.parserLanguage;
                this.name = item.name;
                this.panination = item.panination;
                this.searchPagination = item.searchPagination;
                this.icon = item.icon;
                this.parserSearchSettings = item.parserSearchSettings;
                this.detaliItemType = item.detaliItemType;
                this.onlineDefaultFilter = item.defaultFiter;
                this.onlineSections = item.sections;
                Object.assign(this, item); // add the extra fields
                this.state = "ready";


            }
            else
                this.state = "failed";

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.state = "failed";
        }

        return this;
    }
```

### And here is how I call the methods in the parser

```js
async latest(page: number): Promise <LightItem[]> {
  try {
    if (this.latestFunction)
      return await this.latestFunction(...this.types, page);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return [];
}
```

### Here is the default `types` and `parameters` that I import

```js
this.types = [this,
  Chapter,
  LightItem,
  Filter,
  DetaliItem,
  ParserSearchSettings,
  labelValue,
  DetaliItemType,
  Section,
  NovelReviews,
  HttpClient,
]

this.parameter: Array <string> = [
  "parser",
  "Chapter",
  "LightItem",
  "Filter",
  "DetaliItem",
  "ParserSearchSettings",
  "labelValue",
  "DetaliItemType",
  "Section",
  "NovelReviews",
  "HttpClient"
];
```

### This is the method that takes to long

There is 10 calls, the first 3 calls are fast then it gets slow for some reasion.

note: the methods (`await HttpClient.getHtml(url)`) get html is what taking long, it gets stuck for sometimes

```js
async function getChapters(novelUrl) {
  var page = 1;
  var result = [];
  while (page > 0) {
    var url = novelUrl + "/page-" + page;
    var container = parser.jq(await HttpClient.getHtml(url)).find(".chapter-list a");
    if (!items.hasElements()) {
      page = 0;
      break;
    }

    var resultA = items.map((x) => {
      var ch = new Chapter(x.attr("title").text(), x.attr("href").url());
      if (result.find((a) => a.chapterUrl == ch.chapterUrl && a.name == ch.name) === undefined)
        return ch;
      return undefined;
    }, [])

    if (resultA.length <= 0) {
      page = 0;
      break;
    }
    resultA.forEach((x) => {
      result.push(x);
    });

    page++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Creating functions with `new Function()` is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Why is that? its working and there is no sensitive data that could care about in my app?

Comment: But why would you do that? There are much better ways to create functions.

Comment: Oh, that I did not know? will it accomplish what I want? please post a answer.

Comment: The usage of `new Function()` may actually contribute to the performance difference. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function#description.

Another reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431228/use-of-new-function-and-performance-issues

Comment: Is there anyway I could make this faster ? or is there any way I could do what I want in another way?